# Converting String to integers spaced by spaces Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am receiving input from a text file, in python 3, where three integers are written on one line, with spaces between them.

```
2 4 16
```

I am trying to create three variables, N, K and A from these ints.
I have tried .split() and also tried using lists and map().
Are there any ways to split an input using spaces and saving them to three variables?

A bit like

```
N, K, A = someFunction(input())
print (N)
```

to return

```
2
```

Comment: *Have* you tried using `split`? `N, K, A = '2 4 16'.split()` works just fine; `N == '2'` afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's will work beautifully like this,

```
In [1]: line = "2 4 16"

In [2]: line.split()
Out[2]: ['2', '4', '16']

In [3]: map(int,line.split())
Out[3]: [2, 4, 16]

In [4]: a,b,c = map(int,line.split())

In [5]: a
Out[5]: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this,

```
In [13]: line = "2 4 16"
In [17]: N, K, A = tuple(line.split(" "))
In [18]: N
Out[18]: '2'
In [19]: K
Out[19]: '4'
In [20]: A
Out[20]: '16'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 data=list(map(int,input().split()))
 print(min(data))
```

Comment: While the answer may be correct this is required to provide some explanation alongside the answer.